# How can a pointet to char act like an array?

Tags: string, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers in C.

```
char *name = "HASAN";
```

When I store " HASAN" using char *, the string is stored somewhere in the memory as an array of characters.
I can access to every single character of the string by treating "name" as an array.

```
//second character of HASAN is A.
printf("%c", name[1]);
```

But I have learnt that "name" is just a pointer that stores the address of the first character 'A' of the string "HASAN".
So, how can " name", a pointer act like  an array?

Comment: Because that is how the language is defined. You can index a pointer, and `name[1]` is the same as `*(name+1)`. And in fact, when you pass an array to a function, it *decays* to a pointer.

Comment: It is true that you can access every character as if it as an array, but you can only *read* them, because the data is a "string literal" and cannot be modified.

Comment: I mean you cannot go `name[1] = 'Z';` or `*(name+1) = 'Z';` because it is *read-only*. So it is misleading to say it is the same as `char name[] = "HASAN";` It is different.

Comment: ^^^^ It's also good practice to make it `const`. See e.g. [1](https://godbolt.org/z/EyF2AJ) vs. [2](https://godbolt.org/z/5HDikB).

Comment: In addition to the other comments and answers, it is worth re-emphasising that the language defines `a[n] ` is the same as `*(a+n)`.  This is true not only in the obvious case of characters where each character is 1 byte by definition, but also for other types including `struct`s, etc.  This is because pointer arithmetic like `*(a+3)` does an implicit multiplication of that 3 by the size of the type of `a`.  Eg if `a` is for a 32 byte struct pointing at memory address 1230000, then `a+3` evaluates to point to the memory address 1230096.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It quite simple.

As standards says:

```
*(name + N) == name[N]
```

And it does not matter how `name` is declared as arrays decay to pointers.

```
char *name = "HASAN";
```

or

```
char name[] = "HASAN";
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following two examples:

```
char arr[] = "HASAN"; // array
```

It allocates 6 consecutive bytes of memory and associates the address of the first allocated byte with `arr`.

On the other hand,

```
char ptr* = "HASAN";  // pointer
```

The pointer variable `ptr*` stores 6 consecutive bytes for the variable **and** 4 extra bytes for pointer variable itself and assigns the address of the string literal to `ptr`. So, in this case, a total of 10 bytes are allocated.